# PointCloud library publishing

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a pcl::PointCloud cloud and I need to publish it. It is NOT a kinect camera. Does anyone know how to do this? Is there some good sample code out there? I really need help here....

Thanks in advance,
-Hunter A.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc , argv , "laser_ReadOut");

    ros::NodeHandle handler;

    ros::Subscriber laserReader = handler.subscribe("scan", 10000, scanCallBack);
    ros::Publisher  laserOutput = handler.advertise<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >("/cloud_pcl", 100);

    laserOutput.publish(correctedCloud.makeShared());
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}//end main.
```

correctedCloud is declared above. It is modified after the scan call back is called.

[image: This is the RVIZ error]

[image: This is the output for rostopic echo cloud_pcl]

I am publishing the topic here (This is my research, so I'm afraid the whole code cannot be posted publicly)

```
    void makeOneCloud()
{
    PointCloud combined;
    //matchSlopes();

    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < scans.size(); ++x)
    {
        PointCloud currentCorrected = scans.at(x).getCorrections();
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < currentCorrected.points.size(); ++y)
        {
            double py = currentCorrected.points.at(y).y;
            double px = currentCorrected.points.at(y).x;
            double pZ = Z;

            pcl::PointXYZ toPush;
            toPush.x = px; toPush.y = py; toPush.z = pZ;

            combined.points.push_back(toPush);
        }//end for y
    }//end for x.

    correctedCloud = combined;
    combined.height = 1;
    combined.width = combined.points.size();

    pcl::PCDWriter writer;
    writer.write<pcl::PointXYZ> ("FinalCorrections.pcd", combined, false);
    laserOutput.publish(combined.makeShared());
    ROS_INFO("Corrections Saved!");

    scans.clear();
}//this method combines all the corrected shapes to a single point cloud.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35368/pointcloud-library-publishing/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-06-01**:
Do you ever set the frame_id of the cloud? You'll need to set it to something in order for rviz to display it.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-06-01**:
Thank you! It works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the following code for this...

1. Include the following:

   #include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
2. Set up your publisher:

   typedef pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ PCLCloud;
   ros::Publisher output_pub_ = node_.advertise (output_topic_name.c_str(), 100);
3. Publish your cloud:

   pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ my_cloud;
   output_pub_.publish(my_cloud.makeShared());

**NOTE**: When you attempt to publish the cloud, you must publish it as a pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ::Ptr (that's the purpose of the `makeShared()` function.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-05-31**:
Why can't I visualize this in RVIZ?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-05-31**:
It is visualized as the `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` datatype.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-05-31**:
Yes, but I'm not getting messages... I see the topic, but I don't get the data.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-31**:
Could  you post a minimal example of your publisher? Is the publisher object long-lived or do you destruct it right after calling .publish?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-05-31**:
I added the code to my post. It isn't part of a class. That could be the reason it's troubled.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-05-31**:
What are you exactly trying to do here? The way you have your publish call setup, it will be called once before scanCallback has a chance of getting called (through spin()). You might be publishing an empty cloud only once. Perhaps you want the publish call inside the scan callback function?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-05-31**:
Yes. Could you help me with that?

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-05-31**:
Take a look at this example: [http://cs.utexas.edu/~piyushk/share/messenger.cpp](http://cs.utexas.edu/%7Epiyushk/share/messenger.cpp) This example extends the basic talker/listener roscpp tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber) in the way you want, by republishing the string message.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-05-31**:
Hopefully between the tutorial and this example, you can see how to use the publish call inside the callback, and setup the publisher as a global variable.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-05-31**:
Thank you so much. Still problems... I can see the data being published; however, RVIZ won't display it. Can I give you any info to help solve this?

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-05-31**:
Sure. Could you link your exact code and a screenshot of rviz to the original question.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-06-01**:
I have added your screen shots.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-06-01**:
The frame_id of your cloud is ' '. This cannot be displayed in Rviz. You must provide a frame_id to your cloud to visualize it.